# how to call a PHP class function in another page by a link

Tags: php, html

i have a menu that has an option to retrieve data from the database and show it to the user, i set up a link on an icon, when the user clicks on the icon, i want it to redirect to the php class page and call a function from it, i don't need to pass any parameter to it, i just want to call the function, how can i do this?

the menu

```
<div class="side-menu">
           
    <ul class="menu">
               
      <li class="menu-item">
         <a href="" class="link"> <img class ="optionn" src="option.png" alt="option">
                   <span class="link-text">see menu</span>
         </a>
     </li>
               
   </ul>
</div>
```

the php class page

```
class userRides
{
    
   
function showMenu()
{

//retrieve data and show it
}

//other functions
}
```

Comment: Use php frameworks like [laravel](https://laravel.com/), [CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/) , etc. Without framework, you should check url and branch them to functions manually, it's so difficult and easy to confusable

Answer (score 2):

A PHP class isn't a "page", and doesn't correspond to a particular URL which you can request directly from the browser. To execute the method, you write some PHP code which [includes](https://php.net/include) the file which defines it, and then uses it, e.g.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../classes/userRides.php';
$rides = new userRides;
$rides->showMenu();
```

(Or you can configure an [autoloader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) which automatically triggers the file include when you use the class.)

You then place that code in a file and point your web server at that. For instance, your web server might point at the directory "/home/h.nasserel/website/public", the three lines above in "/home/h.nasserel/website/public/menu.php", and the class in "/home/h.nasserel/website/classes/userRides.php". You would then access "http://something.example.com/menu.php" in your browser, and it would run the PHP code.